# Integrate my Launchpad/Open ID with stack exchange account?

Tags: support, login, stackexchange, launchpad, openid

I am currently using my AskUbuntu account created using Stack Exchange credentials.

Recently started being active on Launchpad. But trying to log in using Launchpad/OpenID credentials makes me create a new user.

Anyway I can get the two login methods to log me into the same user account?

Comment: try this one http://askubuntu.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent

Comment: Worked like a charm...was that a customized url for me? Can you please move to the answer so that I can select it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

https://askubuntu.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent

The way to get the link is:

1. Select your username (the avatar in the new not-technically black bar)
2. Click "My Logins"
3. Click "Add more logins..."
4. Done!